# Injecting module function into AngularJS service

Tags: angularjs

I have been reading these two links [1](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/09/30/requirejs-angularjs-dependency-injection/) and [enter link description here](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide). The idea is to have clean and module code.

The modular approach explained in the links above suggest to a file for the function, and another file for injecting the functions into angular's `directive`, `controller`, ... .

As an example:

```
/* app.js */
define([
    '/path/to/controller',
    '/path/to/service1'
], function(MyController, MyService1))
{
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module('myApp', [])
        .controller('MyController', MyController)
        .factory('MyService1', MyService1);
});

/* controller */
define(function()
{
    "use strict";

    return ['$scope', 'MyService1', MyController];

    function MyController($scope, MyService1) 
    {
        /* Now do your coding here */
    }
});

/* service */
// Identical to controller
```

Notice here how the function is implemented in one file, and then injected into the angular.

Now, I can see a potential problem is your service custom depends on another custom service. Say `MyService2` also uses `MyService1`. My two services now look like:

```
/* MyService1 */
define(function() {
    return MyService1;

    function MyService1() {
        /* Code Here */
    }
});

/* MyService2 */
define(function() {
    return ['MyService1', MyService2];

    function MyService2(MyService1) {
        /* This uses MyService1 here */
    }
});
```

If your app uses both, then all is well, however, if it only uses one, then we have a problem:

```
/* This will work fine */
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController)
    .factory('MyService1', MyService1)
    .factory('MyService2', MyService2);

/* This will NOT */
angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('MyController', MyController)
    .factory('MyService2', MyService2);       <-- This guy internally requires MyServce1
```

I don't see how to solve this problem while still keeping this kind of approach. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RequireJS and AngularJS have two non-overlapping dependency resolution mechanisms. If you're really going to use both, as suggested in the [linked guide](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/09/30/requirejs-angularjs-dependency-injection/) (I'm hard-pressed to imagine a scenario where this would be useful enough), you need to keep in mind, that the individual "service files" don't really contain services at all. They contain just their constructors/factories. To put it all together, your module definition needs to solve both of the separate concerns:

1. load all files with the constructors/factories needed for service/controller/... definitions, and
2. define all things that you don't want to leave as external dependencies.

In other words, if you define a module containing just `service2`, which has a `service1` dependency, and don't define `service1`, then `service1` becomes an external dependency of your module (it cannot be used in an environment where no `service1` is defined).

---

In other words, the two DI frameworks do NOT complement each other so that you could load a file containing a service only when you need to inject it (in Angular) for the first time. You could find a way to use RequireJS to load something (most likely whole separate Angular applications) on demand. But you cannot load a service/controller/... on demand (at runtime), because such things can only be defined in the *configuration phase* of AngularJS application construction. Once the *run phase* starts, no more configuration (e.g. service definition) can be done.

If you just want to create a single application with modular code, I'd suggest that you leave RequireJS be for now and focus on simply creating modular code, as the [style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide) suggests.

Answer (score 0):

i see you use requirejs there so you got 2 dependencies frameworks in parallel (angular and requirejs)

when you define a file that has a dependency on MyService2, than MyService2 needs to define a dependency to MyService1 (requirejs dependency) so both files are loaded and available.
that closes the issue for requirejs file loading.

now angular: in MyService1 you do

```
angular.factory('MyService1', function () {....});
```

than angular knows of that service and can inject it to anyone who needs it.
for MyService2 you do,

```
angular.factory('MyService2', ['MyService1', function(MyService1) {...}]).
```

and now angular injected MyService1 into MyService2 and you can use it in service 1.

than in some controller you need service 2 you just do

```
angular.controller('MyController', ['MyService2', function(MyService2){...}]);
```

and angular injects service 2 that has already service 1 injected into it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know this method. My question was how to use the pattern I gave above. I am basically trying to follow this pattern https://github.com/johnpapa/angularjs-styleguide. It's very clean and nice.

Comment: it would still work, since in the requirejs you defined a dependency to MyService2, wihch defines dependcy to MySErvice1.
MyService1 file would be loaded and it will define itself as a service in angular.

Comment: No, my notation has the actual function in a separate file, and then another file that injects the function into the angular.factory. Yours has `angular.factory('someName', function() {...})` directly.

Comment: I'm going to rephrase the question. I think I can get my point across better that way.

Comment: oh i see. never saw such a strange guideline before. i know some use both angular and requirejs which is ok, but to break it like that is not great. if MyService1 is an angular service, it needs to put itself into the angular object. otherwise it doesn't konw its an angular service wihch lets face it, who are we fooling? its a lot of code that later on will be hard to understand. i'm always for the stupied simple solution, always works best when you later have to actually read that code.

Comment: I understand, I don't know why they then suggest this.

Comment: ya it doesn't feel natural for angular to work that way. people trying to be over smart but i put my confidence in google team that built angular. what you found, is just 1 problem with their pattern, there might be more.